# Context propagation in Java Reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a question with context propagation in Java Reactor. I have below test and don’t understand why it fails when I add additional transformation to the pipeline:

```
@Test
void shouldPropagateContext() {
    var mono = Mono.just("VALUE")
                   // TEST FAILS IF BELOW LINE IS UNCOMMENTED
                   // .flatMap(Mono::just) // or event with .map(p -> p)
                   .defaultIfEmpty("")
                   .flatMap(r -> Mono.<Void>empty()
                           .contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put("key", r)));

    StepVerifier
            .create(mono)
            .expectAccessibleContext()
            .contains("key", "VALUE")
            .then()
            .verifyComplete();
}
```